# is_numeric incorrectly identifies a float (which is a random string)

Tags: php, floating-point, numeric, scientific-notation

I'm looking for numerics in a variable, and if not found I quote the string - otherwise it is left unquoted.  Example:

```
$x = '000916846E38516';
if (is_numeric($x)) { echo 'Numeric!'; } else { echo 'Non-numeric!'; }
```

It so happens that the string is scientific notation, and PHP recognizes it as a number.  How should I work around this?  Would just checking to see if there are alpha characters be better, or is there another function similar to is_numeric that will exclude scientific numbers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`is_int()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) and [`ctype_digit()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) should both work for you.

[`filter_var()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php) might be even better as you can set flags to validate floats (`FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT`) and integers (`FILTER_VALIDATE_INT`)